# Cannot get the same Min(date) for all rows for the same user_id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, looker

I have 4 columns which are:
user_id, 
job_date, 
min(job_date), 
 
rank.

The column that does not show what I want is the min(job_date) column. In that column, I am basically trying to paste the smallest date for a given user_id. I.e. If my first date was 1-1-19, then this date shall show across all columns in the min(job_date) column.

Here is the SQL code:

```
SELECT  
user_id , 
job_date,
min(job_date),
rank() over(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY job_date ASC) AS rank
FROM abc
group by 1,2;
```

The table looks like this:
[image]

The problem: The min_job_date of 2019-04-29T13:24 only shows for the first row but it should show for all rows for the same user_id. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the same window function (although the `ORDER BY` is unnecessary) to determine your `MIN(job_date)` for each user. As has been pointed out by @GordonLinoff, with the use of a window function, it is probably unnecessary to use `GROUP BY` now unless a given user can have more than one job starting on a given `job_date`.

```
SELECT user_id , 
       job_date,
       MIN(job_date) over (PARTITION BY user_id) AS min_job_date,
       RANK() over(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY job_date ASC) AS `rank`
FROM abc
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: . . Ironically, this would (happen to) work with the same `ORDER BY` clause as well, but your version is definitely the right way to express the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your data, but do you actually need aggregation?  That is, are there duplicate rows for a given user on a given date?  Or was the `GROUP BY` just your attempt to get the minimum.

I suspect the latter, so this might do what you want:

```
SELECT user_id, job_date,
       MIN(job_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) as min_job_date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY job_date ASC) AS seqnum
FROM abc;
```

I replaced `RANK()` with `ROW_NUMBER()` because the assumption is that there are no duplicates.

Comment: You are right about the need for aggregation. Given the use of window functions it isn't necessary for this query. It doesn't hurt but definitely not required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're grouping by both the user_id and the job_date, so you get the minimum job_date per job_date... switch to `group by 1`.

However, this alone will return only the minimum job_date per user, if you want to get the minimum column on all rows, you'll need to join it to the result set:

```
SELECT  
abc.user_id , 
job_date,
min_job_date,
rank() over(PARTITION BY abc.user_id ORDER BY job_date ASC) AS rank
FROM abc inner join (
  select user_id, min(job_date) as min_job_date 
  from abc group by user_id
) mjd on abc.user_id = mjd.user_id;
```